# Best way to make images scrollable that where painted on the control

Tags: c#, winforms

I draw images (lets say 200x200) on control in C# depending on how many there are (could be over 100) they get drawn offscreen since they are stacked one above the other. What is the best way to make a dynamic scroll so that i can scroll to the ones that are offscreen.

I was thinking of using a Panel and painting them on there and then just place the Panel on the control. But with the panel being transparent and the control on which the panel is sitting is changing its image (its a map that you can move with draging) the panel lags behind when drawing and creates a ugly jitter effect.

So are there any good solutions where i wont need to implement the whole logic of a scroller myself for such a solution?

Comment: If I understand right you're saying that you've placed up to 100 images on your WinForms form, even though only one (or a few?) are supposed to be visible. If so, I think that is a poor design, and you're asking for responsiveness problems. You should redesign your program so only the images that are visible are actually placed on the form.

Comment: If i do it this way the original problem with scrolling is still there. And there are no performance issues placing 100 images on the winforms with DrawImage, the only performance issue is setting Panel backgroup to Transparent and moving the background on which the Panel is on

Comment: Transparency in WinForms has never worked all that well. WinForms idea of "transparent" is usually just "use the same background color as my container". So it's not really clear what the real concern regarding Transparent is here. As far as the main question goes, have you looked at ListView? It's not 100% bug-free, but it does have a "virtualized" display mode where the control only tracks bitmaps for the items currently being displayed. Again, not sure if it would address your concerns about transparent, but might be worth looking at.

Comment: I can't remember the details, but there's some kind of "double buffer" attribute on the drawing of controls that might help.

Comment: Your description begs for a layout change.  Put a `FlowLayoutPanel` on the form, then add `PictureBox` controls to that flow panel, each with an image.  You get the scrolling and double-buffering for free.

Comment: I suggest at least thinking about drawing not __onto__ a control, no matter which, but instead drawing __into__ a PictureBox's Image. Put the PictureBox inside an autoscroll panel and make it a large as the  Size you need. No jitter, smooth scrolling.. What will be the maximum size you expect? (BTW: Panels are only transparent if you don't set a Background Color. But that is beside the point)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PictureBox` is doublebuffered and will take care of the flicker.

For your case don't draw **onto** a control, no matter which, but instead draw **into** a `PictureBox`'s `Image`.

Put the `PictureBox` inside an autoscroll panel and make it a large as the Size you need. No jitter, smooth scrolling..

Here is an example. It randomly draws around 200 small images into the Image of a `PictureBox`. I create the Image with a large size and I put the PB into a `Panel`:

```
Random R = new Random();
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    panel1.AutoScroll = true;
    pictureBox1.Parent = panel1;
    pictureBox1.Location = Point.Empty;
    pictureBox1.Image = new Bitmap(3000, 500);
    pictureBox1.ClientSize = pictureBox1.Image.Size;

    var imgFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\scrape\", "*.png");
    foreach(string file in imgFiles)
    {
        using (Graphics G = Graphics.FromImage(pictureBox1.Image))
        using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(file))
        {
            if (bmp.Size.Width < 300)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
                    G.DrawImage(bmp, R.Next(2500), R.Next(400));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can easily adapt it to your own project, I'm sure..

Comment: Yes i can implement this